# Cannot insert multiple lines in Sqlite using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I know this is a very simple question but I cannot find any answer that can help me.
I'm using C# in order to connect to a SQLITE database and insert some data.
Here is the code :

```
private void OpenDb()
        {
            this.m_handle = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + m_filename + ".sqlite3;Version=3;");
            this.m_handle.Open();
        }

        private void CloseDb()
        {
            this.m_handle.Close();
        }

        private void CreateDb()
        {
            this.OpenDb();
            string query = "CREATE TABLE StreamingUrl ([url] varchar(255) NOT NULL,  [DateRequest] TEXT NOT NULL);";
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, this.m_handle);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.CloseDb();
        }

        public void AddStreamingUrl(string url)
        {
            this.OpenDb();
            string query = "INSERT INTO StreamingUrl (url, DateRequest) VALUES ('" + url + "', datetime('now', 'localtime'));";
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, this.m_handle);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.CloseDb();
        }
```

I can create the database as well as the table. When I try to insert one data, it works good. However, when I try to add a second row it does not work, sqlite does an update on it (`DateRequest` is updated, so I think the row is updated). My database file is not added to the project as reference or things like that.

When I use SQLiteAdministrator with this insert query, it works. So I think that my code is wrong but I cannot figure it out. I don't have any exception or errors.

EDIT : It may be important but I have two projects in my VS solution : one dll and one exe. The code is in the dll and I run the exe project> I don't know if that changes something.

EDIT2 : Added the code that calls `CreateDb`. It is in my class constructor:

```
this.m_filename = filename;
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(this.m_filename) == false)
            {
                SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(this.m_filename + ".sqlite3");
                this.CreateDb();
            }
```

`AddStreamingUrl` is called by a event so I cannot show you the entire code. Here is the part I think it's interesting :

```
this.NetworkManager.StreamingUrl += Passerelle_StreamingUrl;
```

And after the event is raised :

```
void Passerelle_StreamingUrl(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            log.AddStreamingUrl((e as StreamingUrl).Url);
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the code calling `CreateDb` and `AddStreamingUrl`?

Comment: @Sima - aren't you calling CreateDb more than once (i.e. instead of inserting one row you first create whole new empty db & insert the row) ?

Comment: @Ondrej Svejdar : No I'm not even deleting my database in my code. So if I add a new table with the same name SQLite would have thrown an exception.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on `Passerelle_StreamingUrl` to make sure subsequent calls are using a different URL?

Comment: Passerelle_StreamingUrl is called once. But my url parameter is the same. Does SQLite update the row if one of the column value is the same as the one in the insert query? In this case I still want my row to be inserted

Comment: Ok I was wrong. My constructor was wrong. In fact, I was not checking the existance of the entire filename. So my database was created each time ... It works fine now

Comment: It is usually the case that the problem is in the code that the questioner doesn't put into the question :)

Comment: In this case, it is in the code (constructor). I create a file called filename.sqlite3 and I only check for filename :)